# search engine for mock google page not working

Tags: javascript, html, search-engine

I checked my code for any mistakes but can't figure out why my search engine isn't working. when I click 'google search' I'm supposed to find results for anything I look up but I'm not seeing it do anything. Does anyone see an error or have any suggestions?

```js
let query = document.querySelector('.query');
let btn1 =  document.querySelector('.btn1');

btn1.onclick = function() {
    let url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+ query.value;
    window.open(url, '_self');

}
```

```html
 <div>
            <input type="search" name="" placeholder="  &#128269;" class="query" value="">
        </div>
        <div>
<button class="btn1">Google Search</button>
<button class="btn2">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
<h5>To our local shops and favorite spots, <a class="link">Happy International Small Business Week!</a></h5>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe google rejects _self search. Use a GCS (Google custom search engine) instead. (Create a developer google acoount for this if you haven't one).

Comment: Also related: `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'`